# Threads in client/server application

Tags: java, multithreading

I made client server app, which is joining new clients in new thread each. I want to send information to server like in auction system bidding up value. How Can I check if thread in client class is the same as in server class? If not How Can I check in which Thread on server side is client?

```
package com.multi;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

public class Server {

    public static final int PORT = 5545;
    public static int I = 1;
    public static String[] users = null;
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    private static final String DB_USER = "DBDEMO";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "******";
    private ResultSet res;
    private String sql = null;
    public void startDataBase() {
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("conn done");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void runQuery(){
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from ITEAMS");
            System.out.println("query works");
            while(res.next()){
                System.out.println(res.getString("DESCRIBE"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startServer() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server is waiting for connetions...");
            startDataBase();
            runQuery();
            while (true) {

                Socket socket = server.accept();
                if (socket.isBound()) {

                    System.out.println("user" + I + " connected");
                    ++I;
                }
                new ServerThread(socket).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().startServer();
    }

}
```

//serverthreads

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    String message = null;


    ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(message);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

//client

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Client extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String[] names = new String[]{ "Sara", "Jessica", "Tom", "Emanuel", "Joshua",
            "Kristin", "Kirito", "Goku", "Bulma" };
    private JTextField chatWindow;
    private static int c = 0;

    public void clientJoin(String name) {


            try {
                chatWindow = new JTextField();
                add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
                setSize(300, 150);
                setVisible(true);
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5545);
                chatWindow.setText(name);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(
                        socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
               // System.out.println(name);

              //  System.out.println(name);
//                while (true) {
//                    String readerInput = bufferedReader.readLine();
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 3;i++){
                printWriter.print(name+":" );
                printWriter.println(c+=5+10*Math.random());
                   }
//                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String name : names) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Client().clientJoin(name);
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();
          // System.out.println("ges here");
            c++;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How Can I check if thread in client class is the same as in server class?

Unless the `Client` and `Server` classes are running in the same JVM (i.e. on the same machine and in the same process), they *cannot* share threads.  They cannot be the same.

Furthermore, since the client and server threads are instances of different classes: `Thread` and `ServerThread` respective.  That means that even if `Client` and `Server` were instantiated in the same JVM, the respective threads still could not be the same.

(Two objects with different classes cannot be the same.  Especially threads, since thread equality is determined by object identity.)

---

As you can see, the question makes little sense if you interpret it literally. If you are actually trying to ask something different ... you will need to clarify the question.